# Mathematica Plot: Inconsistency when plotting large values

Tags: plotting, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I am working with a function in Mathematica and I am getting some inconsistencies when I plot it. As I really need to understand were this comes from I would appreciate any help.

I am working with a function of the following form:

`f2b[b_] = 
 Exp[-1000 - 2 Sqrt[1000*b] - b]*(Erfi[Sqrt[1000]] - 
    Erfi[Sqrt[1000] + Sqrt[b]])`

From my understanding this function should go to zero for very small b because both parts, the Exp function as well as the difference between the imaginary error functions, should vanish.

Mathematica calculates:

`f2b[E^-30] // N = -3.4517046881*10^-7` as expected.

BUT if I plot this function:

`Plot[{f2b[E^b], 0}, {b, -50, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica shows me a plot which is approaching a value of about -0.0175 for small b and has therefore an absolute value much larger the the value at E^-30 calculated above.

If I tabulate, interpolate and plot the function:

`t = Table[{b, f2b[E^b] // N}, {b, -50, 0}];
f = Interpolation[t];
Plot[{f[b], 0}, {b, -50, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The plot is looking much different and is approaching zero as expected.

I am wondering whether this has to do something with overflow problems in graphics but I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function isn't evaluating correctly when given inexact input:

```
In[16]:= Table[f2b[N[E^-k]], {k, 0, 50, 10}]

Out[16]= {-0.01730248257001, -0.01784636881283, -0.01785014954397,
          -0.01785017502377, -0.01785017519545, -0.01785017519660}
```

If we force `f2b` to be evaluated with exact inputs (delaying the numericization of the result) we get the expected plot:

```
f2b2[b_?NumericQ] := N[f2b[SetPrecision[b, Infinity]]] 

Plot[{f2b2[E^b], 0}, {b, -50, 0}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help; the answer by Brett Champion solves my problem!
I tried to increase the WorkingPrecision earlier which did not work. Thank You!
Silky

Answer (score 4):

Keeping exact values until the last moment yields this:

```
f2b[b_] := 
 Exp[-1000 - 2 Sqrt[1000*b] - b]*(Erfi[Sqrt[1000]] - 
    Erfi[Sqrt[1000] + Sqrt[b]]);

ticks = Transpose[{Range[8]*10 - 9, Table[x, {x, -50, 20, 10}]}];

Show[ListLinePlot[Table[N[f2b[E^x]], {x, -50, 20}], Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {ticks, ticks}}],
 Graphics[Style[Line[{{51, 0}, {51, -1}}], Antialiasing -> False]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. `N` is superfluous in your code since `ListLinePlot` will apply `N` automatically (see the `InputForm` of `ListLinePlot` with exact values).

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to set `WorkingPrecision` to `Infinity`:

```
f2b[b_?NumericQ]:=Exp[-1000-2 Sqrt[1000*b]-b]*(Erfi[Sqrt[1000]]-Erfi[Sqrt[1000]+Sqrt[b]])
Plot[{f2b[E^b],0},{b,-50,0},PlotStyle->{{Blue,Thick},{Red,Thick}},WorkingPrecision->Infinity]
```

[image: plot]

The above works but it is quite strange that setting `WorkingPrecision` to a value more than 150 results in a very long evaluation giving wrong result.